# copy and deepcopy in Python C API

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-extensions

How does one define `copy` and `deepcopy` methods for a Python type defined in a C extension?

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#tp-slots), there doesn't appear to be a `tp_` slot for these methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no slot. You just define the same methods you'd define in Python, but in C. (Typically, that means implementing `__reduce__` and getting the default `__reduce__`-based `copy.copy` and `copy.deepcopy` behavior, but you can also implement `__copy__` and `__deepcopy__` if you want.)